# Null pointer Exception error on implementing OnClickListener inside a list view

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a list view that shows the list of some contacts with a call and an email option. If call button is pressed then it should make  a call to that person and same with email button.

But Here's what the problem is:- I have written OnClickListener in the list Activity and when I am running it it gives me an error of Null Pointer Exception .

Please guide.Thank you in advance.

Below is my code.

MyActivity.java

```
package com.vanjasrivastava.customlistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

   // Array of strings storing country names
   String[] countries = new String[] {"Mr.Vikas Raina", "Mrs. Jeetu Sharma", "Mr.Kuashik Ghosh", "Mr.Niranjan Lal", "Ms. Swati Garg", "Ms. Manju", "Mr. M. Kakhani", };

   // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
   int[] flags = new int[]{R.drawable.vikas, R.drawable.jeetu, R.drawable.ghosh, R.drawable.nlal,  R.drawable.swati, R.drawable.manju, R.drawable.manish};

  // Array of strings to store currencies
  String[] currency = new String[]{"Assistant Professor", "Assistant Professor", "Assistant Professor", "Assistant Professor", "Assistant Professor", "Assistant Professor", "Assistant Professor",       };

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

  // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
  List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

  for(int i=0;i<7;i++){

    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hm.put("txt", " " + countries[i]);
    hm.put("cur"," " + currency[i]);
    hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
            aList.add(hm);
   }

  // Keys used in Hashmap
  String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

  // Ids of views in listview_layout
  int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};


  SpecialAdapter adapter = new SpecialAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.mylist, from, to);
  // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
  ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);

  // Setting the adapter to the listView
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);

  ImageButton callButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.call);
  ImageButton mailButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.email);
  callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

  if(v.getId()==R.id.email) {

      phoneCall();
      }
     }
  });

  mailButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

     if(v.getId()==R.id.email) {

            sendEmail();
        }
       }
      });
    }

    private void phoneCall() {

        String phoneCallUri ="tel:+91 1573 225001";
        Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));
        startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
    }

    protected void sendEmail() {

        Log.i("Send email", "");

        String[] TO = {"abc@gmail.com"};
        String[] CC = {"xyz@gmail.com"};
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");

        try {

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
            finish();
            Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

SpecialAdapter.java

```
package com.vanjasrivastava.customlistview;

/**
 * Created by vanjasrivastava on 11/21/14.
*/
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    private int[] colors = new int[] { 0x50888888, 0x7500aced };

    public SpecialAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int resource,    String[] from, int[] to) {

        super(context, items, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        int colorPos = position % colors.length;
        view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

mylist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cur"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="0.5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/call"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cl" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/email" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Update:

I did some changes in my code but still It shows Error: 
 at lines 
 1. startActivity(Intent) - The error is "cannot resolve method"
 2. finish() -              The error is : " cannot resolve method"
 3. Toast.makeset() -       The error is :" cannot resolve method"

here is my updated code:

MyActivity.java

```
 package com.vanjasrivastava.customlistview;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.List;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MyActivity extends Activity {

 // Array of strings storing country names
 String[] countries = new String[] { "Mr.Vikas Raina","Mrs. Jeetu Sharma","Mr.Kuashik    Ghosh","Mr.Niranjan Lal","Ms. Swati Garg","Ms. Manju", "Mr. M. Kakhani",};
 // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
 int[] flags = new int[]{R.drawable.vikas,R.drawable.jeetu,R.drawable.ghosh,R.drawable.nlal,     R.drawable.swati,R.drawable.manju,R.drawable.manish};
 // Array of strings to store currencies
 String[] currency = new String[]{"Assistant Professor","Assistant Professor","Assistant Professor",      "Assistant Professor","Assistant Professor","Assistant Professor","Assistant Professor"};

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
 // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
 List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("txt", " " + countries[i]);
        hm.put("cur"," " + currency[i]);
        hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
        aList.add(hm);
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    //SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.mylist, from, to);
    SpecialAdapter adapter = new SpecialAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.mylist, from, to);
    // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
    ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

}
```

SpecialAdapter.java

```
 package com.vanjasrivastava.customlistview;

 /**
 * Created by vanjasrivastava on 11/21/14.
 */
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    private int[] colors = new int[] { 0x50888888, 0x7500aced };
    ImageButton callButton;
    ImageButton mailButton;
    public SpecialAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, items, resource, from, to);
   }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);


    callButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.call);
    mailButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.email);
    callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if (v.getId() == R.id.call) {

                phoneCall();
            }
        }
    });
    mailButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         if (v.getId() == R.id.email) {
                sendEmail();
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
  }
    private void phoneCall()
    {
        String phoneCallUri ="tel:+91 1573 225001";
        Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));
        startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
    }
protected void sendEmail() {
        Log.i("Send email", "");

        String[] TO = {"abc@gmail.com"};
        String[] CC = {"xyz@gmail.com"};
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");


        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");

        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
            finish();
            Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
                            "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


 }
```

How can i resolve these errors. 
Please guide.

Comment: Can you add a logcat?

Comment: Where you implemented `onClickListener` in your `Adapter`?

Comment: Get ID of the Phone/Email button inside Getview method. Write setOnClickListener methods inside getview.

Comment: You wrongly implemented the `onclicklistener`,implement the `onClick` in `SpecialAdapter.class`

Comment: have you seen my answer ? where have you reached with this ? would appreciate if you reply :)

Answer (score 0):

The following lines of code:

```
callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if(v.getId()==R.id.email)
        {

            phoneCall();

        }
    }
});

mailButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.email)
        {

            sendEmail();

        }
    }
});
```

Move the above code to the `getView()` method of `SpecialAdapter`. Also, add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the topmost `LinearLayout` of your `mylist.xml`. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code as follows :

your **SpecialAdapter.java** should like this , and skip the clicklisterner of both buttons from  **MyActivity.java**

```
public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
   private int[] colors = new int[] { 0x50888888, 0x7500aced };
    ImageButton callButton ,mailButton;


   public SpecialAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int  
               resource,    String[] from, int[] to) {
          super(context, items, resource, from, to);

      }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);

    callButton = (ImageButton)view .findViewById(R.id.call);
    mailButton = (ImageButton)view .findViewById(R.id.email);

    callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


         // Here  you get the position of clicked item that you can retrive the value   from
         // array with the help of position

           // phoneCall();


    }
});

   mailButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Here  you get the position of clicked item that you can retrive the value from
         // array with the help of position

          //  sendEmail();


    }
  });

    return view;
  }
}
```

Comment: when I made changes as suggested by you..its showing error at "findViewById".The Error says: :"Cannot resolve method "

Comment: How can I remove the error "Cannot resolve method findViewById(int)" could you please guide?   even it's showing error at lines where I have written "startActivity(Intent) " as well as where I am calling The Toast.maketext().

Comment: please refer this link for more details >> (http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-images-and-text-using-simple-adapter-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

Before anything else, your code does not work as intended as you are checking if the button id is 'email' whenever you press the call button, which yeilds false all the time. You can get rid of those checks, they are redundent.

Also as others have suggested, your onClick method hooks should be done in `getView()` method in your custom adapter.